# Знаки препинания в конструкции "орали как потерпевшие"

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая в предложении

*Парта, за которой орали (?) как потерпевшие (?) три человека?*

Или это устойчивое выражение?

Comment: В примерах из НКРЯ запятая обычно ставится. Мое мнение - не ставить, потому что оборот в некоторой степени фразеологизирован, и это чувствуется.

Comment: "Почему все уличные птицы более или менее молчат, а воробьи орут, как потерпевшие?"  Здесь запятая нужна.  Факультативное обособление  устойчивого оборота, по предложению надо смотреть.

Comment: @Sharon воробьи не могут быть потерпевшими.

Comment: Если они потерпевшие - то выделяется, если они "орут как потерпевшие", но сами потерпевшими не являются - то нет.

Comment: Воробьи орут, как будто (они) потерпевшие.   Любой фразеологизм можно использовать в такой позиции, что его нужно обособить. Послушайте варианты: Воробьи орУт, как потерпЕшие. Воробьи орут как потерпЕшие.  Оба варианта возможны.  А там сопоставление: молчат – орут, нужно его выделить ударением. Вот я и выделяю ударением. Знаки можно ставить  по правилам и проверять варианты по интонации.

Comment: @Sharon Нет, не любой. Обороты, прямое значение которых неясно, не следует отделять, так как неясно, с чем именно сравнивается (*упал как подкошенный*). То есть не следует использовать позицию, при которой надо отделить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Парта, за которой орали **как потерпевшие** три человека...*

1. Сравнение носит **фразеологический** характер и часто применяется в речи,  но это не  повод для однозначного решения (не обособляется). Все зависит **от структуры** предложения.
2. **Значение** оборота: очень громко, эмоционально, беспорядочно.
3. Оборот не обособляется в позиции **наречия.**

Сравнить: *За партой орали три человека, ***как потерпевшие***. *За партой, **как потерпевшие,** орали три человека.**

Comment: Я бы сказал, оборот тесно связан со сказуемым.

Comment: В позиции наречия да, грамматически связан, а по семантике не связан. Его можно заменить наречием громко, то есть это обычный распространитель.

Comment: Спасибо, Серж и Sharon!